# Problema con validación en evento KeyPress Datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview, ascii, keypressevent

Tengo una pequeña duda sobre si la validación que estoy aplicando es correcta o no, básicamente solo quiere permitir que el usuario me digite estos caracteres (r,R,p,p,Back) en el evento key press de mi datagrid, pero al evalularlo solo me permite usar el botón back

```
  private void dataGridPre_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar != (Char)Keys.Back || e.KeyChar == (Char)Keys.Space || e.KeyChar != (Char)Keys.R
            || e.KeyChar != (Char)114 || e.KeyChar != (Char)Keys.P || e.KeyChar != (Char)112)               
                e.Handled = true;
        else
            e.Handled = false;            
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool correcto = (e.KeyChar == 'R') || (e.KeyChar == 'r') || 
                (e.KeyChar == 'P') || (e.KeyChar == 'p') || 
                (e.KeyChar == (char)8);

e.Handled = !correcto;
```

En el **evento KeyPress** pon este código, lo que se hace aquí es preguntar si se tecleó algunos de estos caracteres(**R**, **r**, **P**, **p**, **BackSpace**(en **ASCII** es el **8**)), de haberse tecleado, pues se permite su escritura, en caso contrario pues no se escribe.

Comment: Muchas gracias @japv!